# Unable to create a file and assert its existance

Tags: java, appium, java-io, assertions

I am using JAVA to create a log file, but after creating it, when I assert its existence, I get back a java.lang.AssertionError. I must be doing something simply wrong but I do not know what. Here is the code:

```
File testLogFile = new File("/home/ninad/eclipse-workspace/Log.txt");

testLogFile.createNewFile();

service = builder.withLogFile(testLogFile).build();

service.start

assertTrue(testLogFile.exists());
```

Comment: Is this Java? Why isn't there a `;` at the last of the 4th line?

Comment: Probably you don't have the permission.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few possible explanations:

1. You are not checking the result of the `createNewFile()` call.  It returns true if the file did not exist before AND it has been successfully create.

   By my reading of the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile--), the method *should* throw an `IOException` if it tries to create the file and fails.  But the flipside is that if you don't test the result of the call, you can't be sure that you got a new file.
2. The builder or the service could be removing or renaming the logfile.
3. If the code was part of a multi-threaded application, then another thread could have removed / renamed the file.
4. The file could (in theory) have been removed / renamed by another application.
5. You may have (OS-level) permission to create the file, but not test for its existence.  (It seems a bit far-fetched ... but some OSes have "complicated" permissions systems.)

There could be other things I haven't thought of.  If you provided an MCVE (including the "builder" implementation) we could check.